# errors running HttpWebRequest.GetResponse - 401 unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, sentiment-analysis

I am using Lymbix client library for sentiment analysis.
When I run the code I am getting an error in (WebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse(): 401-Unauthorized

(available at https://github.com/lymbix/.NET-Wrapper)

The function containing 401 error is given below:

```
    private static string Post(string url, string data, List<string> headers)
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        if (headers != null)
        {
            foreach (string header in headers)
            {
                httpRequest.Headers.Add(header);
            }
        }

        // write request?

        byte[] postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString());
        httpRequest.ContentLength = postData.Length;
        httpRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);

        // read response
        WebResponse webResponse = (WebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader webResponseStream = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
        return webResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Comment: No sure about Lymbix but do you need to send them credentials of some kind? 401 error would point to that pretty clearly.

Answer (score 0):

It's saying you're not authorized, so you need to provide [credentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
httpRequest.Method = "POST";
httpRequest.Accept = "application/json";
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username","password");
httpRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = false; //the default is false, but I included it here just to illustrate that it needs to be false in order to use the specified credentials
```